# Django Book Ch. 3: "No Module named mysite.wsgi"

Tags: python, django

I've been stuck on this problem for what seems like forever, and none of the other threads I've found seem to help.

When I run python manage.py runserver in cmd, I get this output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ltiokhin\My Documents\DJCode\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found

Django version 1.4.3, using settings 'settings'

Development server is running at http:___________________________

Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x010689 F0>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
  py", line 109, in inner_run
   handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 24, in get_handler
handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 39, in get_handler
return get_internal_wsgi_application()

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 58, in get_internal_wsgi_application

 "could not import module '%s': %s" % (app_path, module_name, e)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.appli cation' could not be loaded; could not import module 'mysite.wsgi': No module na med mysite.wsgi
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same version as in the book?
Last time I had this kind of error it was because of that!

Or did you add wsgi to the installed_apps in settings.py?

Comment: I'm running Django 1.4.3. and in settings.py, I has wsgi as "WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'"

Comment: I keep thinking it has something to do with the way you started/configure the project. Try to create a new project following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ and if you succeed to run the second one, compare what was different in the setup of those project...

Answer (score 0):

Look for "wsgi.py" under the folder "C:\Documents and Settings\ltiokhin\My Documents\DJCode\mysite\mysite". Its possible that the standard django application file is missing or its named as something else.